# Find the conjugate/similar transformation matrices connecting two unitary irreducible representations corresponding to the same character.

Tags: representation-theory, gap, computational-algebra

In [the GAP manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap71.html#X8493ED7A86FFCB8A),
the following description is given for the command
`IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon`:

> If the option `unitary` is given, GAP tries, at extra cost, to find a
> unitary representation (and will issue an error if it cannot do so).

Suppose I already have a unitary irreducible complex representation for a group. In this case, can I find the conjugate/similar transformation matrices connecting the two unitary irreducible complex representations, i.e., the one used by GAP and the one I already have, of the same group?

I would like to use the following example to provide more information. The group is shown below:

[image]

The corresponding already known character table and the irreducible representations of the generators are shown below:

[image]

The corresponding gap code snippet is as follows:

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("P" ,"Q");;
gap> G8_5:=f/ParseRelators(f, "P^4 = Q^4 = 1, Q*P = P^3*Q, Q^2 = P^2");;
gap> char:= First( Irr( G8_5 ), x -> x[1] = 2 );;
gap> hom:=IrreducibleRepresentationsDixon(G8_5, char: unitary );
[ P, Q ] -> [ [ [ E(4), 0 ], [ 0, -E(4) ] ], [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ] ]
```

Taking the `R5` for example, as you can see, there are two sets of 2-dimensional irreducible representations matrices given by GAP and the ones corresponding to the generators shown in the screenshot.

Based on the above results, I tried to perform the following test:

```
# Create group using the generators of the homomorhpism mapping image: 
gap> matg1:=GroupWithGenerators( MappingGeneratorsImages(hom)[2] );
Group([ [ [ -E(4), 0 ], [ 0, E(4) ] ], [ [ 0, -E(4) ], [ -E(4), 0 ] ] ])
# Create group using the representation matrices given in the screenshot:
gap> matg2:=GroupWithGenerators( [ [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, E(4) ], [ E(4), 0 ] ] ] );
Group([ [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, E(4) ], [ E(4), 0 ] ] ])

gap> iso:=IsomorphismGroups(matg1,matg2);
CompositionMapping( [ [ [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ] ], 
  [ [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ] ] -> [ [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, E(4) ], [ E(4), 0 ] ] ],
 <mapping: Group([ [ [ -E(4), 0 ], [ 0, E(4) ] ], [ [ 0, -E(4) ], [ -E(4), 0 ] ] ]) -> Group(
[ [ [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ] ]) > )

gap> Source(iso)=matg1; Range(iso)=matg2;
true
true

gap> IsCompositionMappingRep(iso);
true
gap> ConstituentsCompositionMapping(iso);
[ <mapping: Group([ [ [ E(4), 0 ], [ 0, -E(4) ] ], [ [ 0, E(4) ], [ E(4), 0 ] ] ]) -> Group(
    [ [ [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ], 
      [ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ] ] ]) >, 
  [ [ [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ], 
      [ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ] ] ] -> 
    [ [ [ 0, 1 ], [ -1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, E(4) ], [ E(4), 0 ] ] ] ]
```

As you can see, `matg1` and `matg2` are two isomorphic matrix groups. There should exist an infinite number of conjugate or similar transformations connecting them, which corresponding to different bases selection, i.e., conjugating the matrix group by some invertible matrix. In order to identify/create/find one of them, I tried with the following code snippet, but in vain:

```
gap> ds_matg1:=DirectSumMat( matg1.1, matg1.2 );
[ [ -E(4), 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, E(4), 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ] ]
gap> ds_matg2:=DirectSumMat( matg2.1, matg2.2 );
[ [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, E(4) ], [ 0, 0, E(4), 0 ] ]
gap> 
gap> ds:=Group(ds_matg1,ds_matg2 );
<matrix group with 2 generators>
gap> 
gap> for i in Elements(ds) do
>   if ds_matg1^i = ds_matg2 then
>       Print(i,"\n",ds_matg1^i,"\n",ds_matg2," \n\n ");
>   fi;
> od;
```

---

P.S.

1. It seems that the `is_similar` function provided by `sagemath` is exactly for this purpose, as described [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix2.html#sage.matrix.matrix2.Matrix.is_similar).
2. See [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2532981) for a related discussion of this issue.

Regards,
HZ

Comment: Do you know that the two representations are isomorphic? Otherwise, there will not be such a matrix. (There can be non-isomorphic irreducibles of the same dimension,  for example.)

Comment: @paulgarrett This is exactly the problem I want to solve: I've two set of matrices of the representations, how to check/confirm the isomorphism between them?

Comment: Do you know about the _character_ $\chi_\rho$ of a group representation $\rho$? $\chi_\rho(g)={\mathrm trace}(\rho(g))$...

Comment: I've the group representations of the generators from which the elements' representations can be computed, as shown in the full example I've added in the OP, FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality for testing of equivalence of representations (using the MeatAxe functionality, see `MTX.IsomorphismModules` in the manual) currently only works over finite fields.
The reason for not extending the implementation to characteristic 0 is  that

- Equivalence for finite group representations in characteristic 0 can be determined using only the character.
- The need to go to a larger field extension makes such a test potentially much more costly in characteristic 0, than over finite fields.

Comment: 1. Thank you for your explanation. [Here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap69.html#X8040270F791514C8) is the manual entry of `MTX.IsomorphismModules`.     2. As for my problem, I'm still puzzled by the result give GAP: `<mapping: Group([ [ [ E(4), 0 ], [ 0, -E(4) ] ], [ [ 0, E(4) ], [ E(4), 0 ] ] ]) -> Group(
[ [ [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ], [ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ] ] 
 ]) >`. Would you give me more explanations about the meaning of this mapping?

Comment: The mapping is a composition of two homomorphisms, with a 4-dimensional group in between. Look at `Source` and `Range` of it, and they will be the 2-dimensional groups you gave.

Comment: I've checked the `Source` and `Range` of the homomorphism as represented in the OP. But how are they related to this 4-dimensional group, what are the specific mapping functions?

Comment: Can I understand it this way: The mapping itself is a real representation, while `Source` and `Range` are two complex representations?

Comment: The 4-dimensional group is an intermediate object used by the mapping for efficiency. Just ignore it, if you find it confusing.

Comment: Anyway, as you can see, `matg1` and `matg2` are two isomorphic matrix groups. There should exist an infinite number of conjugacy or similar transformations connecting them. How to identify/create/find one of them?